# How do I find the average % of grade level enrollment by school across each state and school year

Tags: postgresql

I want to find the average percent of grade level enrollment by school across each state and school year. Below is the table I created, and below that is my query to get the answer. I get an error message telling me I can't use AVG on a window function by I don't know how else to rewrite the Query. (This is in Postgre SQL btw)

```
 CREATE TABLE Enrollment (School_ID int, 
                      District_ID int, 
                      School_year text, 
                      St_A text,
                      Grade_level text, 
                      Enrollment int);
        
INSERT INTO Enrollment VALUES
    (1, 100, 'SY22_23','NY','Gr2',56),
    (2, 200,'SY22_23','CA','Gr4', 78),
    (3, 300,'SY22_23','CO', 'Gr1', 102),
    (4, 400, 'SY22_23','TX', 'Gr4', 202),
     (5, 500, 'SY24_25','DC','Gr3', 105),
    (6, 600,'SY24_25','CA','Gr4', 69),
    (7, 700,'SY24_25','AZ', 'Gr2', 91),
    (8, 800, 'SY24_25','TX', 'Gr3', 98),
    (9, 900, 'SY23_24','DC','Gr4',56),
    (10, 1000,'SY23_24','DC','Gr1', 60),
    (11, 1100,'SY23_24','TX', 'Gr3',65),
    (12, 1200, 'SY23_24','NY', 'Gr2', 70),
    (1, 100, 'SY22_23','NY','Gr3',56),
    (1, 200,'SY22_23','CA','Gr2', 78),
    (3, 300,'SY22_23','CO', 'Gr4', 102),
    (4, 400, 'SY22_23','TX', 'Gr3', 202),
     (5, 500, 'SY24_25','DC','Gr2', 105),
    (6, 600,'SY24_25','CA','Gr4', 69),
    (7, 700,'SY24_25','AZ', 'Gr3', 91),
    (8, 800, 'SY24_25','TX', 'Gr1', 98),
    (9, 900, 'SY23_24','DC','Gr1',56),
    (10, 1000,'SY23_24','DC','Gr2', 60),
    (11, 1100,'SY23_24','TX', 'Gr3',65),
    (12, 1200, 'SY23_24','NY', 'Gr4', 70);
```

My Query Answer:

```
SELECT School_Year, St_A, Enrollment, School_ID, Grade_level,
AVG(cast(Enrollment as float)/(SUM(Enrollment) OVER (Partition by School_ID))) AS AVG_percent,
From Enrollment
GROUP BY Grade_level
ORDER BY St_A, School_year
```

Answer (score 0):

Although intuitively your query is right, there are a few logical problems.
You cannot use window functions within aggregate functions in the SELECT clause.

For this case, to calculate the average percent of grade level enrollment by school across each state and schol year, you can just use a subquery to calculate the total enrollment for each school and then join that with the main `Enrollment` table.

THe PostgreSQL implementation of the above mentioned idea would be:

```sql
SELECT 
    School_year, 
    St_A, 
    School_ID, 
    Grade_level, 
    AVG(CAST(Enrollment AS FLOAT) / total_enrollment) AS AVG_percent
FROM (
    SELECT 
        School_year, 
        St_A, 
        School_ID, 
        Grade_level, 
        Enrollment,
        SUM(Enrollment) OVER (PARTITION BY School_ID) AS total_enrollment
    FROM Enrollment
) AS subquery
GROUP BY School_year, St_A, School_ID, Grade_level, total_enrollment
ORDER BY St_A, School_year;
```

It is not the best solution but it serves as a good starting point for optimization. Test it out [here (fiddle)](https://dbfiddle.uk/q5mm84aO)